# Automated webpage performance metrics from multiple external data sources

Tags: google-analytics, google-data-studio, stripe

We currently use google sheets to pull together performance of webpages across the multiple platforms they integrate with. It's a laborious, manual process.

We have a long list of pages from our website, one per row in gSheets, all with completely different URLs (making a regex-based solution out-of-the-question).

We manually grab stats from analytics (uniques, time on page, etc), our CRM (list subscribers originating from that page), facebook ad manager (reach, clicks, spend etc), and stripe (transactions from that page, etc).

It's an effort-intensive process, but once the data is in sheets, we can quickly do math on the combined stats and see if we're on track for KPIs like CTR, conversion rates, etc.

I am reaching out to see if there's a tool to automate some/all of the pulling in of data from analytics/ CRM, facebook, stripe, etc?

It looks like the analytics addon for sheets relies on regex filtering, meaning it won't scale and can't be easily manipulated by nontechies. Things like Retool and Stitch only allow you to pull in a small amount of metrics, so doesn't work. Google data studio doesn't seem to offer page-by-page granularity.

Is there anything out there that can work for me, either inside google sheets or using a completely different tool?

We currently have one row per URL and then columns for each of the external data metrics, which can then be manipulated/reported on/aggregated/factored into formulae.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Recommend this question be moved to [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)